# What does the phrase "spot-on physics" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase **spot-on physics** in the following sentence (not available online) from the description of the game Pixel Pro Golf:

> The game may look old-school but its **spot-on physics** add a
> realistic, modern feel.

Here is a description of the game from Apple App Store:

> Play through 20 gorgeous pixelated courses, each carefully crafted
> with a unique style and conditions, as you try to become the best of
> the best.
>
> Use the simple controls to aim, change club and swing. Then watch your
> ball head down stunning pixel fairways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The game may look old-school but its spot-on physics add a realistic, modern feel.

The physics of the game are "**spot-on**", which implies that they're very well made, accurate and realistic.

Some reference:

"**spot on**" - From the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spot-on)

> exactly right

Synonyms include:

- accurate
- exact
- on point

Answer (score 3):

What Melon Dusk said, except that

a) while "the spot-on physics" is hyphenated, "the physics is spot on" isn't, and

b) physics, like mathematics, is singular.

In any case, it indeed means that the physics is accurate; that the objects in the game move just like real objects do.